# word wrap does not work on when window is resized on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, resize, window, word-wrap

I have a simple html layout that has 3 divs. The divs are separated by a border line. The middle div has long text. I am breaking the long text by applying the style word-wrap:break-word. The issue is on **window resize** ( when the window is smaller in size), the text is getting overlapped with the border line. This is happening only on IE (version 11) but works well with chrome and FF.

Please advise on how to resolve the window resize text alignment issue on IE.
Here's the html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border-right-style: solid;border-width:1px;">
        text goes here
        </div>
         <div style="border-right-style: solid;border-width:1px;">
            <span style="word-wrap:break-word;"> XX-standard-com.longtext.nogoodexperience.howtoresolve_nofix.yyy</span>
         </div>
        <div>
        XX-standard-com.longtext.nogoodexperience.howtoresolve_nofix.yyy
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `span` is a inline element. Try using a `div` or making it `display: block`.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border-right-style: solid;border-width:1px;">
        text goes here
        </div>
         <div style="border-right-style: solid;border-width:1px;">
            <span style="word-wrap:break-word; display: block;"> XX-standard-com.longtext.nogoodexperience.howtoresolve_nofix.yyy</span>
         </div>
        <div>
        XX-standard-com.longtext.nogoodexperience.howtoresolve_nofix.yyy
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I also tried to use an ellipsis css

Answer (score 0):

`break-word` is a non-standard addition that is implemented by WebKit browsers, but not by IE. See [word-break | CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

You can use any of the other word-break values, for instance:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

If you think `break-word` looks nicer, you can add them both, in the right order:

```
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
```

This should make WebKit browsers use `break-word`. IE doesn't support this, and should ignore that rule, falling back to `break-all`.

Comment: I tried word-break: break-all but does not work on window resize

Comment: I tried to use both break-word and break-all as you 'd suggested. Things work fine with full window. The moment I resize the window and increase and decrease the size, that's when IE does not respond well with long text. My long text is crossing the border line of the div.